# What's the mapping of the "Interviews with Monster Girls" manga to its anime?

Tags: interviews-with-monster-girls

What's the mapping of the "Interviews with Monster Girls" manga to its anime?

I'm wondering where to see certain scenes in anime form, but dunno where to look.